# Integer optimization, OR-TOOLS how to constrain workers to "set of tasks"

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, or-tools

I am currently trying to figure out how to do the following optimization problem:

A Worker can be assigned to 0 or 1 task.
A Task can have 0 or 1 worker.
There is a clear cost for a given worker --> task.  This is very straight forward (and well documented).  See solution: (https://developers.google.com/optimization/assignment/assignment_example)

However, I have 3 "versions" of tasks, call them:

Version A Task 1, Version A Task 2 ...

Version B Task 1, Version B Task 2 ...

Version C Task 1, Version C Task 2 ...

A worker can be assigned to any version of the task, but ALL workers must be assigned the same Version.  Ie,  Worker 1 can be in Version A Task 1,  or Version B Task 1...but once you have constrained Worker 1 to Version A, all workers must use Version A. The cost function for worker-->task remains meaningful across Versions.

A contrived example of this is, I have a 10 workers.  I have 3 factories each with X number of tasks.  I wish to optimize productivity by having workers do X at a factory, But I only have one "bus" to transport them.  I can only send all 10 workers to any 1 factory.

A naive approach is to split the problem into 3, solve it 3 times, once per version and then pick the version with the lowest cost.  However, I am wondering if there is a way to constrain the problem to solve it all in one go.  Especially since solving the problem once is rather time-expensive.

Comment: Start with a piece of paper and begin writing down the mathematical model for this problem. Once you have this, transcribing it into a form that can be consumed by a solver is quite easy.

Comment: hints?  currently i'm using np.concat(list_of_costs, axis=1) and then trying to use: solver.add(Some constraints) by indexing to check that that the indexes are grouped and it is not pretty nor working

Comment: Don't think about code, think first about the mathematical model. So forget initially about things like np.concat. That is the wrong abstraction level.